# When did Edea die?

Tags: bravely-default

In the third world (Chapter 6), in Sage Yulyana's sidequest to get the Conjurer Asterisk (after awakening 2 crystals) you learn from Dark Knight Alternis Dim, Templar Braev Lee and his wife/Edea's mother Mahzer Lee that the Edea of that world is dead.

However, at the start of the chapter, in a side quest before awakening any Crystals, Black Mage Ominas Crowe was expecting Edea to arrive to serve under his command. Before the fight with Knight Argent Heinkel, he questioned why Edea wasn't with Crowe.

After beating Braev Lee, he said Edea's sword was sent back to after her death. I can't think of why Ominas or Argent would have given a false report considering they just fought Edea and lost, or even how they got a hold of third world's Edea's sword, yet not show any surprise that Edea was actually alive (unlike Braev or Mahzer).

So I am wondering, when did Edea of the third world die? And were the Eternian Sky Knights forces in Caldisla not informed?

Comment: Been a while since I played this - where in the third world did you fight Braev? I think I revisited Central Command in all worlds but never could find him.

Comment: @Omega after awakening 2 crystals and seeing Yulyana you get a new Sidequest from him, first you fight Alternis in Edea's room in Central Command, Yulyana then will tell the party to go to the Central White Magic Tower (where Mahzer is treated) and that's where you fight Braev, after that you'll then go to the hidden village, find Olivia and fight the Venus sisters (which explains why they are missing too initially), then he'll tell you to go to where Norende was and you find Til and fight some random monsters